# Unchecked lastError value Error: Frame not found, or missing host permission

Tags: firefox, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-webextensions

I hope y'all are doing good. So I'm facing this error in my firefox extension. Not exactly sure what I'm missing but for sure I have the correct permission settings in my manifest.json file. I attached it as well. I would appreciate your help on understanding in a general sense what would be the cause of such an error. And just as a note this doesn't happen in chrome

Manifest.json snippet

```json
"permissions": ["<all_urls>","webRequest","webRequestBlocking","nativeMessaging","tabs","history","storage","unlimitedStorage"],
"content_scripts": [
  {
   "matches": ["<all_urls>"],
   "css": ["background.css"],
   "js": ["content.js"]
  }
 ],
"background": {
  "scripts": [
   "global.js","background.js"
 ]
},
```

[image: Error Image]

Comment: Assuming it's executeScript, the frame seems to have been removed by the time injection was performed.

Comment: please provide a snippet of background.js as well as expand the error message for the stacktrace